# Add custom labels to default spring boot actuator metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I'm currently working on a Spring boot (webflux) project where we have exposed metrics of our application on **/actuator/prometheus** endpoint using spring boot actuator dependency which by default gave us for example: **http_server_requests_seconds_bucket** metric. By default it has **{exception="None",method="POST",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/test",le="0.268435456",}** labels. I want to add another label say "challenge" which depends on the request payload. For example, my request payload looks like this,

```
{
 "type" : "basic",
 "method" : "someMethod"
}
```

I want to add a label within that metric as, `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{exception="None",...,challenge="basic"}` which is based on the request payload "type" parameter. Can someone tell me how can I add custom label to the existing default metric provided by spring-boot-actuator

**Note:** We only have limited number of values for "type" so that it doesn't explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I found we can do this by extending a class called **DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider** (for Spring MVC) and adding custom tag.

```
@Component
public class CustomTagsAdder extends DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider {

@Override
public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Throwable exception) {

    List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    tags.add(Tag.of("CUSTOM_TAG_KEY", "CUSTOM_TAG_VALUE")); // Repeat this line for each of the tags you want


    for(Tag tag : super.getTags(request, response, handler, exception))
        tags.add(tag);

    return tags;
}
}
```

Similarly for webflux projects you can extend **DefaultWebFluxTagsProvider** and add your custom tags.